# Python: sets and set.intersection - random order of output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have a question about the un-ordered nature of sets.

This code:

```
#Set1 is 'a' to 'e' in alpha order
set1 = {}
set1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
print('\nSet1 :', set1)

#Set2 is 'f' to 'a' (missing 'e') in reverse-alpha order
set2 = {}
set2 = {'f', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'}
print ('Set2 :',  set2)

print ('Common to both sets:',  set1.intersection(set2))
```

...gives random ordering of the elements in `set1`, `set2` and in the result of `set.intersection`:

```
Set : {'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'}
Set: {'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'f'}
Common to both sets: {'a', 'c', 'b', 'd'}
```

Although not a problem per se, my question is this: is there a set algorithm for this? Or could I (feasibly) use this property to generate random lists of items present in two lists (i.e. is it truly random?). BTW, I have no idea why I might want to do this - thinking out loud.

Comment: Sets are not ordered.  You can't rely on elements in sets having any particular order, nor can you rely on them being "random".

Comment: @BrenBarn Apart from removal of duplicates, then, their use must be pretty esoteric. I will stick to lists and tuples while I am still in week 1 of learning Python. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt No, not esoteric at all. While lists and tuples are more common, I frequently encounter data that neither had a meaningful order nor needs to be forced into some order for my code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which sets are printed is based on, among other things, a hash of their contents - it is not random. If you need a set to be ordered, you can always use the built-in `sorted()` function:

```
>>>> sorted(set1.intersection(set2))
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

Comment: Not only on their hash, also on the size of the container and its history of insertions and deletions, and sometimes even on a random seed.

Comment: @delnan - I know it was more than just the hash, but I didn't know about the random seed. What purpose does that serve?

Comment: I should mention for completeness that it affects the hashes of strings and the like, not hashables as such, it's technically already included in "the hash of their contents". As for purpose: It was intended to prevent hash DOS attacks (send specially crafted requests that cause the server to build a hash table with numerous collisions). Some people (I believe tem, but not everyone on python-dev seems to agree) say it's trivial to adapt these attacks to circumvent the seed.

Comment: @delnan Thank you for the answer. While waiting, I tried running this about 30 times. There seemed to be no pattern to the `set.intersection` order, so with each set element being just one character long there must be some additional random seed involved.

@MattDMo Many thanks for this - this was new to me.